# Get input of fully connected layer of ResNet model during runtime

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, pytorch-lightning

Found a Solution, left it as an answer to this question down below :)

Info about the project: Classification task with 2 classes.

I am trying to get the output of the fully connected layer of my model for each image I put into the model during runtime. I plan to use them after the model is done training or testing all images to visualize with UMAP.

The model:

```
#Load resnet
def get_model():
    model = torchvision.models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
    num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
    model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)
    return model
```

The relevant part of pl module:

```
class classifierModel(pl.LightningModule):
   def __init__(self, model):
     super().__init__()
     self.model = model
     self.learning_rate = 0.0001

def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x= batch['image']
        y = batch['targets']
        x_hat = self.model(x)
        output = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
        loss= output(x_hat,y)
        return loss
 
def test_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
        x= batch['image']
        y = batch['targets']
        x_hat = self.model(x)
```

Is it possible to do this by adding a empty list to the init of the pl module and then add the output after `x_hat = model(x)` is executed?
How would i know if after `x_hat = model(x)` is executed, the out_features aren't immediatly deleted/discarded ?

Comment: Sorry, but can you elaborate with an example. say "some input" and then "the current output" or "the desired output"?

Comment: So basically i want to give the CNN some imput (x). The current output are two scores, one for each class. My desired output is the values of the fully connected layer of shape [1, 2048] .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do this using a forward hook on the avgpool layer and saving the output on each test_step like described [here](https://kozodoi.me/python/deep%20learning/pytorch/tutorial/2021/05/27/extracting-features.html) :

```
#Define Hook: 
def get_features(name):
    def hook(model, input, output):
        features[name] = output.detach()
    return hook
```

Now when I load my model, I register the hook:

```
#Load resnet model:
def get_model():
    model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)
    num_ftrs = model.fc.in_features
    model.fc = nn.Linear(num_ftrs, 2)
    model.avgpool.register_forward_hook(get_features('feats')) #register the hook
    return model
```

I did not need to change the init of the pytorch lightning model but the test step function:

```
FEATS = []
# placeholder for batch features
features = {}

class classifierModel(pl.LightningModule):
   def __init__(self, model):
     super().__init__()
     self.model = model
     self.learning_rate = 0.0001

def test_step(self, batch,batch_idx):
        x= batch['image']
        y = batch['targets']
        x_hat = self.model(x)
        FEATS.append(features['feats'].cpu().numpy()) #added this line to save output
```

now we have the output `FEATS[0].shape --> (16, 2048, 1, 1)` which is what i wanted to get(16 is the batchsize is use).

Answer (score 1):

`x_hat` is this vector and is `[batch_size, 2048]`. So just modify your training step to also return `x_hat`.

```
class classifierModel(pl.LightningModule):
   def __init__(self, model):
     super().__init__()
     self.model = model
     self.learning_rate = 0.0001
     self.fc_outputs = []

   def training_step(self, batch, batch_idx):
       x= batch['image']
       y = batch['targets']
       x_hat = self.model(x)
       self.fc_outputs.append(x_hat)
       output = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
       loss= output(x_hat,y)
       return loss
```

The values of `x_hat` will not be deleted unless you explicitly call `del x_hat` BEFORE assigning these values elsewhere. In the case where you have already assigned the values of `x_hat` to another variable (in your case it sounds like you want to append it to a list) the memory addresses associated with the values are not deallocated because there is still a variable that references these addresses even after the original variable referencing them (`x_hat` may have been deleted). In this way, python is relatively safe in terms of memory referencing because it dynamically computes when memory addresses / values are no longer needed at runtime.

Comment: Thank you, but the shape of x_hat is actually [batch_size, 2] since in the model I set the fully connected layer to `model.fc = nn.linear(2048,2)` to train the model on two classes/ get results on two classes.

Comment: Then no, you cannot get the results of an intermediate layer without modifying the source code of `ResNet` slightly so that this variable is persistently stored. It would be trivial to do, but you cannot accomplish this in your training script.